# Access $firebaseObject value with variable instead of string

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to assign a variable to a string and pass that variable to a Firebase query in a $firebaseObject. But, when I try this, the firebaseObject is null. I tried with directly putting the string in and it works, but I don't want that.

Code:

```
//var itemkey='-JyO7Zsgsucf5ESttJwt';
var itemkey=window.localStorage['fbid'];-------> string: '-JyO7Zsgsucf5ESttJwt'
console.log(typeof itemkey); ------------------> string
$scope.galphoto = $firebaseObject(ref.child(itemkey));
console.log($scope.galphoto) ------------------> null
```

When I call

```
$scope.galphoto = $firebaseObject(ref.child(itemkey));
```

With `itemkey='-JyO7Zsgsucf5ESttJwt'`,

then `console.log($scope.galphoto)` is properly shown. However, when I use what I really want to use,

```
window.localStorage['fbid']
```

then `console.log($scope.galphoto)` is null.

Why?

Comment: Does the string have any leading / trailing whitespace? Try `var itemkey = window.localStorage.getItem('fbid').trim();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be trying to console.log the result before it's available. $firebaseObject returns the data with some delay. You may try to do something like

```
$scope.galphoto = $firebaseObject(ref.child(itemkey));
$scope.galphoto.$loaded().then(function () {
    console.log($scope.galphoto);
}
```

You should see the expected result, since you're waiting for the promise to respond. It could help you better understand how to get the desired result.